# Problem with swift polymorphism and dynamic type

Tags: swift, inheritance, dynamic, polymorphism, dynamictype

I just encountered a strange behavior in swift's inheritance handling, when it comes to polymorphism and dynamic types. The following code shows the problem I encounter, which basically is: The dynamic type is recognized correctly (printed by `print("type(of: self) = \(classType)")`), but the generic function `testGeneric` uses the wrong type.

```
class Global {
    static func testGeneric<T: TestSuperClass>(of type: T.Type) {
        print("T.Type = \(T.self)")
    }
}

class TestSuperClass {
    func run() {
        let classType = type(of: self)
        print("type(of: self) = \(classType)")
        Global.testGeneric(of: classType)
    }
}

class TestClass: TestSuperClass {

}

class TestClass2: TestSuperClass {
    override func run() {
        let classType = type(of: self)
        print("type(of: self) = \(classType)")
        Global.testGeneric(of: classType)
    }
}

let testClass = TestClass()
let testClass2 = TestClass2()

testClass.run()
testClass2.run()
```

the printed output is

> type(of: self) = TestClass
>   T.Type = TestSuperClass
>   type(of: self) = TestClass2
>   T.Type = TestClass2

So basically when calling `testClass.run()`, `type(of: self)` yields `TestClass`, which I would expect. The problem then is that the generic function `testGeneric`, which is called immediately afterwards, somehow does not work with type `TestClass`, but uses `TestSuperClass` instead.

What I personally would expect is

> type(of: self) = TestClass
>   T.Type = TestClass
>   type(of: self) = TestClass2
>   T.Type = TestClass2

i.e., the generic function `testGeneric` using the type `TestClass` instead of `TestSuperClass` when called via `testClass.run()`.

**Questions:**
- Do you have an explanation for that?
- How can I obtain the behavior I had in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, the compiler want's to know at *compile time* which generic type to "infer". Therefore, the type system will bind to the static type. There is no such thing as *dynamic type inference*.

Therefore the compiler generates the following  (see comments):

```
class TestSuperClass {
    func run() {
        let classType = type(of: self)  // static MetaType TestSuperClass.Type
        print("type(of: self) = \(classType)") // dynamic type: TestClass
        Global.testGeneric(of: classType)  // infer to static type, i.e. testGeneric<TestSuperClass>
    }
}
```

As a result, `T.self` is `TestSuperClass` in your case, because that's what the compiler is able to see:

```
static func testGeneric<T: TestSuperClass>(of type: T.Type) {
    print("T.Type = \(T.self)")
}
```

What you maybe want is the following:

```
static func testGeneric<T: TestSuperClass>(of type: T.Type) {
    print("T.Type = \(type)")
}
```

Here, you do not print the type of `T`, but the (dynamic) value of the parameter `type`, which in your case is `TestClass`

Comment: Do you have any idea how to handle a generic function like this `static func returnObjects<T: TestSuperClass>(of type: T.Type) -> [T]` then? (code as above, just switch out testGeneric with returnObjects). So basically `T` should vary based on dynamic type, but with your explanation above it does not, which my tests do confirm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second question: You will not be able to change the dynamic type of the retured array; it will always be `[TestSuperClass]` - although it will contain `TestClass` objects:

```
class Global {
    static func testGeneric<T: TestSuperClass>(of type: T.Type) {
        print("T.Type = \(T.self)")
    }
    static func returnObjects<T: TestSuperClass>(of theType: T.Type) -> [T] {
        let newObj = theType.init()
        let newObjType = type(of:newObj)
        print("type(of: newObj) = \(newObjType)")
        return [newObj]
    }
}

class TestSuperClass {
    required init() {
        print ("TestSuperClass.init")
    }

    func run() {
        let classType = type(of: self)
        print("type(of: self) = \(classType)")
        Global.testGeneric(of: classType)
        let array = Global.returnObjects(of: classType)
        let arrayType = type(of:array)
        print("type(of: self) = \(arrayType)")

        print (array)
    }
}

class TestClass: TestSuperClass {
    required init() {
        super.init()
        print("TestClass.init")
    }

}

let testClass = TestClass()
testClass.run()
```

> TestSuperClass.init
>   TestClass.init
>   type(of: self) = TestClass
>   T.Type = TestSuperClass
>   TestSuperClass.init
>   TestClass.init
>   type(of: newObj) = TestClass
>   type(of: self) = Array < TestSuperClass >
>   [__lldb_expr_21.TestClass]

Comment: Thanks, that gave me some ideas on how to handle my task at hand.